# Custom Column Names in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am building a scheduling application and want to use the fullcalendar API to do so. In one of the views I want to design, I need the column names to not be the names of the day, ie. instead of 'Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday', I want the names to be 'Day 1, Day 2, Day 3' etc. I have achieved this for 7 days by using the dayNames property.

```
dayNames: ["Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4", "Day 5", "Day 6", "Day 7", "Day 8"]
```

But for a duration of more than a week, I get 'Day 1, Day 2,... Day 7, Day 1' i.e, instead of going to Day 8 the column name rolls over to Day 1. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTtxt.png)

One solution I thought of was to change the text after the calendar has loaded From Day 1 to Day 8 by using JQuery. But I think that, that would take more effort to do and that there might be an easier way to do it.

To sum it up, I want to give my calendar custom day names without having it rollover names after the 7th name. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to achieve this only using the initialization options. I believe you will need to use javascript / jQuery.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I ended up doing. Surprisingly only took six lines of code. Still wish there would be an easier way though.